# What is the conversion rate between dry malt extract (DME) and liquid malt extract (LME)?

Tags: extract, conversion

Say I have a recipe that calls for 5 lbs of LME.  How much DME would that be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### In short: 4.2 lbs DME

DME = 0.84 * LME

LME = 1.19 * DME

### The whyfor

It depends on the manufacturer. Extracts and malts and adjuncts all have a "points per pound per gallon" rating that you can look up from the supplier.  *In general*, dry malt extract gives you 44 pppg and liquid 37 pppg.

5 pounds of LME gives you 185 points. To get the equivalent points from DME you divide by 44 to get 4.2 pounds.

This is related to [my answer](/a/1059/333) of Jordan's question about all grain conversion to extract. Also read the Homebrew Talk's wiki page for [Dry Malt Extract](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Dry_Malt_Extract) and [Liquid Malt Extract](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Liquid_Malt_Extract).

Answer (score 3):

The conversion rate is 1 DME = 1.25 LME.  To get the opposite, you would divide.

For your recipe specifically, use 4 lbs DME.

Comment: Where'd you get that conversion?

Comment: I she means  LME  =  1.25 * DME , the same as saying 4 pounds of DME is equal to 5 pounds of LME which is from "How to brew" by John Palmer.